# liberty-arquillian container adapter not reading server.env file

Tags: java, websphere-liberty, jboss-arquillian, open-liberty

**Issue Overview**
When running an arquillian liberty managed container test, the specifiec environment variables are not resolved in the server.xml file. WLPManagedContainer.class can be seen trying to find the server.env, however, a running app in the runtime using server.env is not resolved during testing.

**Expected Behaviour**
A server.xml file containing e.g.  and foo=bar defined in server.env in the running server directory. Should be resolved during the in-container test.
When fetching the jndiEntry using @Resource(lookup="env/foo") String foo; should resolve to bar in runtime as well as during arquillian testing
See: https://github.com/HasseNasse/liberty-arquillian-envvars

**Current Behaviour**
Application servlet resolves @Resource(lookup="env/foo") String foo; to bar during application deployment. Whilst during Arquillian testing the @Resource(lookup="env/foo") String foo; resolves to ${env.foo}, as defined in server.xml.

Tested using both Java 11 (Azul Zulu) and Java 8 (Azul Zulu + Oracle JDK)

**Steps To Reproduce**
*Running Arquillian test:*

1. git clone
   https://github.com/HasseNasse/liberty-arquillian-envvars.git
2. mvn verify

*Deploying Application*

1. git clone https://github.com/HasseNasse/liberty-arquillian-envvars.git
2. mvn liberty:start-server
3. cp target/ target/liberty/wlp/user/servers/defaultserver/dropins
4. Navigate to http://localhost:9080/net_nazarsit_arq_war/foo

Comment: it looks like you've found a valid bug in the liberty-arquillian plugin. Can you please raise an issue on the github repo? https://github.com/OpenLiberty/liberty-arquillian That would be a more appropriate place to track it than on SO

Comment: @AndyGuibert Right on! https://github.com/OpenLiberty/liberty-arquillian/issues/40